# Columns don't wrap properly when there are more than 12 columns in a row and they are of different height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this:

```
.col-xs-2 {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.col-xs-2:hover {
    height: 25px;
}
```

(Or you could visit [this page](http://www.bootply.com/B0hIIOkkdD) instead)

Initially all the columns are of the same height and and they appear as two rows of items, one below the other. So far so good.

On hovering over a div it's height increases by 5px and the new row starts at after this div and not at the beginning. It like the rest of the row to leave 5px space (or whatever is required) and start at the beginning.

Note: This occurs even if the size of a div is greater than that of other divs in its row initially.

So far I've tried setting margin-top, padding-top and float:left but haven't had much success.

PS: I have more than 12 columns per row because the elements are being generated dynamically and this works seamlessly on devices of different sizes. At least till someone hovers over a div.

Comment: You need to not modify grid elements with styling. I almost never apply custom classes or other modifiers to containers, rows, or columns. Modify the elements inside the grid, and allow space for the hover effect on initial load. Hover effects that shift the entire page around are fatiguing and annoying to visitors.

Comment: @isherwood - Haha! Yes, I just noticed that even after making the proper changes it doesn't feel all that good doing this. I'm going to make things visible right from the beginning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap includes CSS to fix this problem, described at [Responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) in the docs.

You'll want to add something like this after each sixth column:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.bootply.com/2Dw6RXQWB8)? It isn't working. Could you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Okay, figured it out. I had to use `<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>` to ensure that it worked on all screen sizes. It didn't just propagate (?) from `xs` to `lg`!